# Do something with ajax-loaded iframe content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

I load some content (simple web form) to iframe (from my domain) via fancybox. And want to add valu to one input in this iframe form.

Try this:

```
$x("a.load_html_i").fancybox({
'type'              :'iframe',
'padding'           : 20,
'width'             : 690,
'height'            : 550,
'onComplete'        : function() {
$x('#fancybox-frame input[name=input_text_0]').val($x(this).attr('title'));
}
});
```

where #fancybox-frame is id of iframe.

And this:

```
...
$x("#fancybox-frame").contents().find("input[name=input_text_0]").val($x(this).attr('title'));
...
```

But it's not work.

Comment: Is the page you are loading in through an iframe on the same domain as the page making the request with fancybox?

Comment: Do you have a working example that I can see?

Comment: It may be the case that 'this' is out of context. Have you performed a console.log on 'this'?

Comment: http://sdam-piter.ru/posutochnaya-arenda.html?start=6 blue button after image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem: jquery runs before iframe loaded. How to improve it?

```
$x("iframe#fancybox-frame").ready(function(){
                $x("iframe#fancybox-frame").contents().find("input[name=input_text_0]").val('hh');
            });
```

adding ready not help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the 'this' keyword, reference the anchor by it's class name. I believe 'this' is referencing the fancybox instantiation.

```
$x("a.load_html_i").fancybox({
'type'              :'iframe',
'padding'           : 20,
'width'             : 690,
'height'            : 550,
'onComplete'        : function() {
//cache the anchor
var anchor = $x(this);
//trigger the following function in 0.5s (should be long enough)
   setTimeout(function(){
      $x('#fancybox-frame input[name=input_text_0]').val(anchor.attr('title'));
   }, 500);
}
});
```

Comment: That's surprising considering it's inside an onComplete callback function...If that's the case just set a timeout within the onComplete callback. See above.